# get mean of dataframe

Tags: r, mean

I have a dataframe

```
df
score
1                2291
2                3548
3                2595
4                3214
5                3275
6                 251
7                  47
8                  47
9                  47
10               2490
```

However when I do this before I take a mean:

```
as.numeric(unlist(df))
[1] 1 7 4 5 6 3 8 8 8 2
```

I am getting completely different numbers.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: What is the `class` of the `score` column?  i.e. `class(df$score)`

Comment: the class is `factor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the column you're operating on has class `factor` (per your comment), you'll get erroneous numbers when calling `as.numeric()` on it directly. To correct this, first change the column to class `character`, then to class `numeric` with

```
df$score <- as.numeric(as.character(df$score))
```

and you should be okay.

Furthermore, you can find the means of the numeric columns more easily with

```
colMeans(df)
```